# React, responsive bootstrap rows and cols

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a react component that maps over some data and displays rows of products. I made a mapping function that also chunks the data upfront based upon the screen size, so everything will fit into a row and there is no weird behavior with the floats and products being slightly different sizes. Here is what I have  now:

```
renderProducts() {
    if (this.props.display && this.props.display.productList && this.props.display.productList.hits) {
      const chunkedProducts = chunkProductsForWindow(this.props.display.productList.hits);

      return chunkedProducts.map((row) => (
        <div className="row">
          {
           row.map((product, index) => (
             <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" key={index}>
              <h2>{product.product_name}</h2>
              <i>{product.product_name}</i>
              <p>${product.price}</p>
              <Link to={`/product/${product.product_id}`}>details</Link>
            </div>
           ))
         }
         </div>
      ));
    }
    return null;
  }
```

And the chunk function looks like so :

```
 function chunkProductsForWindow(products) {
  let chunkSize;
  const windowSize = window.innerWidth;

  if (windowSize >= 992) {
    chunkSize = 4;
  } else if (windowSize < 992 && windowSize >= 768) {
    chunkSize = 2;
  } else {
    chunkSize = 1;
  }

  return _.chunk(products, chunkSize);
}
```

So, this works fine for me when the page loads. it gets weird when you drag the page around because nothing is re-calculating the chunk size when the user changes the screen size. I am trying to **avoid** putting a listener on the window size, so what I am wondering is - is there a better way to do this where the wrapping rows would change based on the screen size - the simpler the better.

There are no renders called when the screen size is just being dragged around so I don't think I can tap into react lifecycle events. Wondering if there is a more elegant solution that doesn't require screen size listeners (trying to keep this app as performant as possible). Thanks for reading!

*EDIT* - added code pen for clarity - https://codepen.io/ajmajma/pen/RGmRXE

For example, start the window small (refresh the page if you need so it reads the initial chunk size as 1), then drag it to large sizes, you will see the products remain in single rows.

Comment: hey there, anyway you can throw up the basics in a fiddle?

Comment: @gwar9 added one in for you.

Comment: fascinating, I will play around and get back to you shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have to listen to window resize to trigger recalculation and re-render. I would put chuckSize as a component state. But dont call setState on every window resize callback. Instead only call setState when you reach the breakpoints. And you can make window resize callback throttle to increase the performance.

Edit
This answer got accepted because of one of the comments below. I copy paste that to avoid confusions...

> But in your case your chunkProductsForWindow function and bootstrap
>   grid are doing the same thing. Having both makes it non responsive.
>   You can remove chunkProductsForWindow and just let grid do its job.
>   codepen codepen.io/anon/pen/dpEOoy

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, I am trying to avoid doing this - looking for alternative solutions. Thanks.

Comment: I dont think you can do it without listening on window resize. Maybe you can find a wrapper component that make your code get rid of it but the wrapper component still needs to listen to window resize.

Comment: I didn't think so either... which is why I am asking the question :)

Comment: ah OK sorry now I fully understand your question. I saw this question with reactjs tag so I am thinking in the javascript way lol. But in your case your chunkProductsForWindow function and bootstrap grid are doing the same thing. Having both makes it non responsive. You can remove chunkProductsForWindow and just let grid do its job. codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpEOoy

Comment: That's what I'm looking for :), great job and thanks!